# How to efficiently exit a python program if any exception is raised/caught

Tags: python, exception

Say I have a block of exception statements:

```
try:
    expression
except err1:
    #process error
    ...
    ...
except err10:
    #process error
```

and I want to call `sys.exit(1)` if ANY of the exceptions are raised. Do I have to call it manually in every single sub-block or is there a built in way to have a statement akin to:

```
    ...
except err10:
    #process error
"if any of these exception were raised":
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Whenever an `except` block is entered, you can `raise SystemExit` after doing whatever you need to do with each error. If none of your `except` blocks actually `raise` an error, you can set a variable initially, then in the `try` block make that value truthy, and then if that variable is falsey after running through any excpetion, raise `SystemExit` at the end. LMK if you'd like a code example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One thing you could do is:

```
flag = False

try:
    expression
    flag = True
except err1:
    #process error
    ...
    ...
except err10:
    #process error
if not flag:
    sys.exit(1) #exit program
```

If the flag is False, that means that you didn’t pass through the `try` loop, and so an error was raised.

Answer (score 4):

In Python, there is an optional `else` block which is executed in case no exception is raised. You may use this to set a flag for you code and exit the code out of the `try/except` block as:

```
is_exception = True

try:
    expression
except err1:
    # ... something
except err10:
    # ... something else
else:
    # This will be executed if there is no exception
    is_exception = False

if is_exception:
    sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
raised = True
try:
    expression
except err1:
    # process error
    raise

...

except err10:
    # process error
    raise
else:
    # if no error was raised
    raised = False
finally:
    if raised:
        raise SystemExit
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I was talking about in my comment:

```
isok = False
try:
    #try to do something
    isok = True
except err1:
    #do something besides raising an exception
except err5:
    #do something besides raising an exception
if not isok:
    raise SystemExit
```